# TSQL - Partition BY if in order

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am trying to partition by [Status] after it's sorted by [Status_DateTime] DESC.
So only [Status] that are in a row will be partitioned in order to get the earliest Date for it.

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Order_Status]    Script Date: 1/13/2017 1:06:38 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order_Status](
    [Case_No_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [Status_Datetime] [datetime] NULL,
    [Employee_ID] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Order_Status] ([Case_No_ID], [Status], [Status_Datetime], [Employee_ID]) VALUES     
(223079, N'HP - HOLD FOR PARTS', CAST(N'2015-12-21T16:44:50.000' AS DateTime), 740)
,(223079, N'DP - ORDER CREATED', CAST(N'2015-12-21T16:45:11.000' AS DateTime), 740)
,(223079, N'PP - PRINT PL', CAST(N'2015-12-21T16:47:03.000' AS DateTime), 709)
,(223079, N'PS- PARTS SHIPPED', CAST(N'2015-12-21T17:50:39.000' AS DateTime), 824)
,(223079, N'OS - MACHINE RECEIVED', CAST(N'2015-12-29T09:47:34.000' AS DateTime), 2)
,(223079, N'RP - UNDER INSPECTION', CAST(N'2015-12-30T12:14:07.000' AS DateTime), 168)
,(223079, N'RP - UNDER INSPECTION', CAST(N'2015-12-30T13:41:01.000' AS DateTime), 168)
,(223079, N'RP - UNDER INSPECTION', CAST(N'2016-01-05T14:15:46.000' AS DateTime), 241)
,(223079, N'RP - UNDER INSPECTION', CAST(N'2016-01-06T13:44:18.000' AS DateTime), 13)
,(223079, N'HP - HOLD FOR PARTS', CAST(N'2016-01-07T14:18:59.000' AS DateTime), 710)
,(223079, N'RELEASED FROM HOLD FOR PART', CAST(N'2016-01-11T16:37:49.000' AS DateTime), 710)
,(223079, N'RP - UNDER INSPECTION', CAST(N'2016-01-12T08:58:05.000' AS DateTime), 241)
,(223079, N'HP - HOLD FOR PARTS', CAST(N'2016-01-20T09:50:19.000' AS DateTime), 710)
,(223079, N'HP06 - PARTS SHORTAGE, PLANNER CONFIRM ETA AND TRIGGER EDI', CAST(N'2016-01-25T15:32:19.000' AS DateTime), 755)
,(223079, N'HP06 - PARTS SHORTAGE, PLANNER CONFIRM ETA AND TRIGGER EDI', CAST(N'2016-03-04T15:56:52.000' AS DateTime), 755)
,(223079, N'HP06 - PARTS SHORTAGE, PLANNER CONFIRM ETA AND TRIGGER EDI', CAST(N'2016-05-16T14:57:12.000' AS DateTime), 755)
,(223079, N'HP06 - PARTS SHORTAGE, PLANNER CONFIRM ETA AND TRIGGER EDI', CAST(N'2016-06-14T15:35:14.000' AS DateTime), 755)
,(223079, N'HP06 - PARTS SHORTAGE, PLANNER CONFIRM ETA AND TRIGGER EDI', CAST(N'2016-08-15T15:28:32.000' AS DateTime), 755)
GO
```

Update:
How can I use Order BY before Partition BY?
If a certain status is duplicated in a 2 consecutive rows, I am trying get the first datetime, If the status haven't changed but the Status_DateTime did.

For example:

```
Case_No_ID  Status                                                                                               Status_DateTime         First_Time              Employee_ID
----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------
223079      HP06 - PARTS SHORTAGE, PLANNER CONFIRM ETA AND TRIGGER EDI                                           2016-08-15 15:28:32.000 2016-01-25 15:32:19.000 755
223079      HP06 - PARTS SHORTAGE, PLANNER CONFIRM ETA AND TRIGGER EDI                                           2016-06-14 15:35:14.000 2016-01-25 15:32:19.000 755
223079      HP06 - PARTS SHORTAGE, PLANNER CONFIRM ETA AND TRIGGER EDI                                           2016-05-16 14:57:12.000 2016-01-25 15:32:19.000 755
223079      HP06 - PARTS SHORTAGE, PLANNER CONFIRM ETA AND TRIGGER EDI                                           2016-03-04 15:56:52.000 2016-01-25 15:32:19.000 755
223079      HP06 - PARTS SHORTAGE, PLANNER CONFIRM ETA AND TRIGGER EDI                                           2016-01-25 15:32:19.000 2016-01-25 15:32:19.000 755
```

Without affecting the ones that are not in a row for example : 'HP - HOLD FOR PARTS' below

```
Case_No_ID  Status                                                                                               Status_DateTime         First_Time              Employee_ID
----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------
    223079      HP - HOLD FOR PARTS                                                                                  2016-01-20 09:50:19.000 2016-01-20 09:50:19.000 710
    223079      RP - UNDER INSPECTION                                                                                2016-01-12 08:58:05.000 2016-01-12 08:58:05.000 241
    223079      RELEASED FROM HOLD FOR PART                                                                          2016-01-11 16:37:49.000 2016-01-11 16:37:49.000 710
    223079      HP - HOLD FOR PARTS                                                                                  2016-01-07 14:18:59.000 2016-01-07 14:18:59.000 710
    223079      RP - UNDER INSPECTION                                                                                2016-01-06 13:44:18.000 2016-01-06 13:44:18.000 13
```

I tried the following:

```
Select 
    ROW_NUMBER() Over (order by status_Datetime Desc) rownum
    , Case_No_ID
    , Status
    , Status_DateTime 
    , First_value(Status_DateTime) over (partition by [status] Order by [status] Desc) First_Time
    , Employee_ID
from Order_Status
where Case_No_ID = 223079
order by Status_DateTime desc
```

It worked fine if the status change was in consecutive order (rows 1 to 5) First time it went to the status was '2016-01-25 15:32:19.000' and since the status didn't change, but If you check First_Time column on row 6 it shows Status_DateTime from row 9, but there was status change between them.

```
rownum               Case_No_ID  Status                                                                                               Status_DateTime         First_Time              Employee_ID
-------------------- ----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------
1                    223079      HP06 - PARTS SHORTAGE, PLANNER CONFIRM ETA AND TRIGGER EDI                                           2016-08-15 15:28:32.000 2016-08-15 15:28:32.000 755
2                    223079      HP06 - PARTS SHORTAGE, PLANNER CONFIRM ETA AND TRIGGER EDI                                           2016-06-14 15:35:14.000 2016-08-15 15:28:32.000 755
3                    223079      HP06 - PARTS SHORTAGE, PLANNER CONFIRM ETA AND TRIGGER EDI                                           2016-05-16 14:57:12.000 2016-08-15 15:28:32.000 755
4                    223079      HP06 - PARTS SHORTAGE, PLANNER CONFIRM ETA AND TRIGGER EDI                                           2016-03-04 15:56:52.000 2016-08-15 15:28:32.000 755
5                    223079      HP06 - PARTS SHORTAGE, PLANNER CONFIRM ETA AND TRIGGER EDI                                           2016-01-25 15:32:19.000 2016-08-15 15:28:32.000 755
6                    223079      HP - HOLD FOR PARTS                                                                                  2016-01-20 09:50:19.000 2015-12-21 16:44:50.000 710
7                    223079      RP - UNDER INSPECTION                                                                                2016-01-12 08:58:05.000 2016-01-12 08:58:05.000 241
8                    223079      RELEASED FROM HOLD FOR PART                                                                          2016-01-11 16:37:49.000 2016-01-11 16:37:49.000 710
9                    223079      HP - HOLD FOR PARTS                                                                                  2016-01-07 14:18:59.000 2015-12-21 16:44:50.000 710
10                   223079      RP - UNDER INSPECTION                                                                                2016-01-06 13:44:18.000 2016-01-12 08:58:05.000 13
11                   223079      RP - UNDER INSPECTION                                                                                2016-01-05 14:15:46.000 2016-01-12 08:58:05.000 241
12                   223079      RP - UNDER INSPECTION                                                                                2015-12-30 13:41:01.000 2016-01-12 08:58:05.000 168
13                   223079      RP - UNDER INSPECTION                                                                                2015-12-30 12:14:07.000 2016-01-12 08:58:05.000 168
14                   223079      OS - MACHINE RECEIVED                                                                                2015-12-29 09:47:34.000 2015-12-29 09:47:34.000 2
15                   223079      PS- PARTS SHIPPED                                                                                    2015-12-21 17:50:39.000 2015-12-21 17:50:39.000 824
16                   223079      PP - PRINT PL                                                                                        2015-12-21 16:47:03.000 2015-12-21 16:47:03.000 709
17                   223079      DP - ORDER CREATED                                                                                   2015-12-21 16:45:11.000 2015-12-21 16:45:11.000 740
18                   223079      HP - HOLD FOR PARTS                                                                                  2015-12-21 16:44:50.000 2015-12-21 16:44:50.000 740
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it presents a _goal_, but lacks a _question_. Nor does it have any indication of research or an attempt at reaching the goal.

Comment: I'm not following what you want.  The last two result samples don't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Specify the question.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: @HABO, Goal is equivalent to question. Which is how to achieve the goal. Anyway I updated my post. The indication of a research was the post itself, since we are supposed to research before posting. anyway I also added what I tried.

Comment: @SQLChao Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Comment: Could you please provide the dataset you would like to receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need something like this. This uses running total over lag to group the consecutive statuses into same group, and then use the first_value partition by that:

```
select case_no_id, status, status_datetime, first_value(status_datetime) over (partition by GRP order by status_datetime desc), employee_id
from ( 
    select sum(case when Status = prev_status then 0 else 1 end) over (order by Status_datetime desc) as GRP, * 
    from (
        select *, lag(status) over (order by Status_Datetime desc) as prev_status from Order_Status 
    ) X
) Y
order by Status_Datetime desc
```

Your example in [rextester](http://rextester.com/ENZC29805)

Comment: Very close, but with the example you provided on restester it's showing the last Datetime for that status, not the first. (on line 1, the date should be from line 5)

Comment: If I change the DESC to ASC in the FIRST_VALUE it works great!. select case_no_id, status, status_datetime, first_value(status_datetime) over (partition by GRP order by status_datetime ASC), employee_id
from ( 
    select sum(case when Status = prev_status then 0 else 1 end) over (order by Status_datetime desc) as GRP, * 
    from (
        select *, lag(status) over (order by Status_Datetime desc) as prev_status from Order_Status 
    ) X
) Y
order by Status_Datetime desc

Answer (score 1):

One method just uses `lag()` to look at the previous status and keep only the ones where it has changed:

```
select os.*
from (select os.*,
             lag(status) over (partition by Case_No_ID order by Status_Datetime) as prev_status
      from Order_Status os
     ) os
where prev_status is null or prev_status <> status;
```

Comment: Thank you, that does it, but I would be loosing the ability to find the last employee_id for the status.

Comment: @AdamS . . .  Your question doesn't even seem to mention employee id.